# Selenium - click on Automatic Random Generated DIV/ID/LINK

Tags: java, random, selenium, click

I'm trying to make a walkthrough with Selenium on a website used to search the cheapest flights. I've been able to make in run through all the search process, but now I'm stuck by the flight selection. I manage to order the flights by company name. And now I need to click on the two first flights (departure, arrival).

As you can see on the attached image, the webpage generates two tables. Each of them has some flights listed. I nee to click on the first one of each table.

The problem is that the generated list uses different DIV IDs for the different companies and that the IDs have random numbers ("_X", X being a random number).

I just need to click on of the DIVs on each table, any comlumn should make it. But all columns use the same name (on both tables).

Using selenium IDE work now, but just for a few hours, because flights, prices, hours are updated constantly and the webpage shows different results each time, which means different IDs each time.

Is there a way to solve this?

IMPORTANT : I'm using JAVA with Selenium. No PERL, no PYTHON or other.

This would be the Steps using JAVA now:

```
// This orders the departure flight by company.
selenium.click("id=orden-compania-ida");
selenium.click("id=orden-compania-ida");

// This orders the arrival flights by company.
selenium.click("id=orden-compania-vuelta");
selenium.click("id=orden-compania-vuelta");

// This would click on the first link of first table
selenium.click("css=div.col-3 > label");
selenium.click("id=I_5");

// This would click on the first link of the second table
selenium.click("css=#TV_GDSAMADEUS_7 > div.col-3 > label");
selenium.click("id=V_12");
```

At this moment this works, but after a flight update, this will not work anymore. Is there any way to make selenium click the right first flight of each table all the times?

Thanks a lot in advance.

[LINK TO IMAGE](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/1872/iberiae.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try to select necessary DIVs by CSS selectors instead of using ID ones. Please go through the following peace of code to figure out what I exactly mean.

```
    // Open Firefox driver.
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Send a get request.
    driver.get("http://google.com");

    // Typing a search query.
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchField.sendKeys("Cheese!");

    // Waiting for the driver to change its title and load search results.
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains("cheese");
        }
    });

    // Obtain dymamically loaded search results.
    List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h3.r"));

    // Go through the search results
    for (WebElement element : results) {
        // You can click instead of printing.
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }

    // Close the driver.
    driver.close();
```

It's an [edited example from the Official Selenium site](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Selenium RC, not webdriver. And "driver.findElements" is not supported...